# Bounding the modified Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: inequality, asymptotics, special-functions, approximation

i'm looking for an upper bound for the modified Bessel function of the first kind of a +ive real argument. It seems that it satisfies the inequality :
$$I_{n}(x)\leqslant \frac{x^{n}}{2^{n}n!}e^{x}$$
But i'm not able to prove this.

Comment: I can prove it for $0 \leq x \leq 4$ from the power series.  Would that be useful to you?

Comment: How did you get this bound?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was proved by Yudell L. Luke in 1972 that

$$
1 < \Gamma(\nu+1)\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^\nu I_\nu(x) < \cosh x
$$

for $x > 0$ and $\nu > -1/2$.  This implies your inequality since

$$
\cosh x - e^x = -\sinh x < 0
$$

for $x > 0$ and hence

$$
\cosh x < e^x
$$

for $x > 0$.

> Yudell L. Luke, *Inequalities for generalized hypergeometric functions*,
>   Journal of Approximation Theory, Volume 5, Issue 1, January 1972, pp. 41–65.
>
> [(Link to the article on ScienceDirect)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-9045%2872%2990028-7)

Comment: Dear Antonio, this answer has helped us in deriving bounds for our paper : https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7314-bayesian-pose-graph-optimization-via-bingham-distributions-and-tempered-geodesic-mcmc (see supplementary). @thmusic and myself would like to thank you for this good pointer and we acknowledge this contribution within the main paper.

Comment: @TolgaBirdal cheers, I'm glad you found this answer useful :)