# Upper bound on the modified Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: inequality, special-functions

I am looking for an upper bound tighter than $e^x$ for the modified Bessel function of the first kind. 
Does there exist $\epsilon\in (0,1)$ such that $I_0(x)\le e^{x^{1-\epsilon}}$ for all $x\ge 0$ ?

Comment: Using $\cosh x$ instead of $e^x$ gives a slightly better upper bound.  See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/415987/5531).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not exist.  In fact, we have the asymptotic,
$$I_0(x) \sim \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}$$
as $x \rightarrow +\infty$, so we can't get any improvement on the exponent.